# Python vectorized running max of parallel line segments

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large number of independent, parallel horizontal line segments in a numpy array. Each segment has a start and an end (x-coordinates), and a value (y-coordinate). The segments don't necessarily have the same length (length = end - start).

An example matrix specifying the segments, one segment per row, could look as follows:

```
Start End Value
0     10  4
5     19  3
6     25  2
7     16  1
12    21  5
```

In code

```
A = np.array([[0,10,4],
[5,19,3],
[6,25,2],
[7,16,1],
[12,21,5]])
```

I want to figure out the running max over the line segments. That is, in the above example, for x in the range [0,25), I want the corresponding max y. Example output corresponding to the example would be

```
Start End Max
0     10  4
10    12  3
12    21  5
21    25  2
```

I can do this in a for loop, but this is slow, since I have tens of thousands of segments. I cannot seem to think of a way to vectorize this. Can anyone?

Example for loop code:

```
x = np.arange(np.min(A[:,0]), np.max(A[:,1]))
maxes = np.zeros((x.shape[0], 2))
maxes[:,0] = x
maxes[:,1] = -np.inf

for a in A:
    ix = (x >= a[0]) & (x < a[1]) & (maxes[:,1] < a[2])
    maxes[ix,1] = a[2]
```

This code outputs an array with a row for every x in the range, contrary to the output example above. Both are fine (and equivalent).

Comment: Add sample case for the numpy array? Also, could there be overlaps between segments?

Comment: @Divakar: thanks for the questions. If you mean an example array, see the example I provided in the first code block. Yes, there can be overlaps; see the example in the first code block.

Comment: @Matt I guess Divakar is talking about adding an **executable** sample case for the array, which can be copied to the python console and will yield an array which looks exactly like your provided sample data.

Comment: @Scotty1- Ok, added the code snippet. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Great, thanks alot! Now posting your for-loop to show how you have done it until now would be great and helpful. :)

Comment: @Scotty1- Done. Thanks for helping make the question clearer.

Comment: You are welcome. Unluckily I don't know if I can help you. It looks like you are altering one of the masking conditions (`maxes`) inside the loop, thus I am not sure if the loop can be avoided. Perhaps this can be resolved using [np.nditer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html) with some outer looping, but I am not good at this. :( Hopefully someone else will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean array to determine if a given point in the space is in a given line segment. That boolean array can be multiplied with the segment values to generate an array where each point on the line has a vector of segment values, and if a segment doesn't include the point, the value is of that segment is zeroed out. From there array's `max` method can be applied along a single axis.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0,10,4],
[5,19,3],
[6,25,2],
[7,16,1],
[12,21,5]])

# get the dimension of the space
seg_left = A[:, 0, None]
seg_right = A[:, 1, None]
seg_val = A[:, 2, None]

# set the left edge of the space and reset the axes
left_edge = seg_left.min()
seg_left -= left_edge
seg_right -= left_edge
right_edge = seg_right.max()


# generate an array of coordinates and repeat it for each defined segment. This 
# can then be used to determine what segments are on for each point
space = np.tile(np.arange(right_edge+1), (seg_val.size, 1))
space_bool = np.logical_and(space >= seg_left,
                            space < seg_right)

# find the maximum of the on segments
seg_max = (seg_val * space_bool).max(axis=0)

# determine the continuous segments. The +1 ensures that the correct value is
# selected
steps = np.r_[0, np.where(np.diff(seg_max))[0]+1]
seg_val = seg_max[steps[:-1]]

# reset the left edge to the original left edge
steps += left_edge

print(np.c_[steps[:-1], steps[1:], seg_val])

# [[ 0 10  4]
#  [10 12  3]
#  [12 21  5]
#  [21 25  2]]
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Props for making a generic solution for any range of x-coordinates. The only problem I have is that, because I have tens of thousands of segments, the `space` array will take up ~47GB of memory, which doesn't fit. But maybe I can chunk it up somehow and then apply a correction to deal with chunk transitions.

Comment: Chunking should work. The other thing you can look into is sparse matrices. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html If your segments are relatively short that will free up a lot of space. I'm not quite sure how to build the sparse matrix without a for-loop, but that may still save a bunch of time.

Comment: just FYI, in the end, I ended up doing the following: create an array of segments of the form <coordinate,value,type>, where type in {start,end} and coordinate is start or end coordinate depending on type. Then loop through it, and use `sortedcontainers.SortedDict` to maintain the max. This took 3 seconds and has no memory issues. (Your approach took ~60 seconds, the original for loop took ~6 minutes.).

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays of `booleans` for indexing of arrays. This means that you can check all your coordinates against your conditions at once and then index the value column (`A[2]`) with the result. From your example results I take it that the end points of the line segments should not be included, hence the following code:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(
    [[0,10,4],
     [5,19,3],
     [6,25,2],
     [7,16,1],
     [12,21,5]]
)

ranges = np.array([
    [0,10], [10,12], [12,21], [21,25]
])

for xmin,xmax in ranges:
    print(xmin,xmax, np.max(A[~np.logical_or(A[:,1]<=xmin, A[:,0]>=xmax),2]))
```

reproduces your desired result:

```
0 10 4
10 12 3
12 21 5
21 25 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but one of the main components of the problem is actually figuring out the `ranges`, which you have hardcoded :)

Comment: @Matt oh, then I misunderstood your question. Would there be any point in thinking about this further, or are you happy with the other answer?